# How to write a '1=1' within dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, code-injection

Can someone please correct this?

```
declare @g varchar(max)
set @g = 'select *
from person.person
where firstname like '%t' '
set @g = @g + 'or firstname  like''' +('a'= 'a')+ ''''

exec (@g)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain what you are trying to do.  Your attempt at a query makes no sense.

Comment: Im using SQL Server and I'm trying to do an injection but every time I try to plug the sql injection I just get an error so I decided to script it out with dynamic SQL.

Comment: what do you mean by this code `set @g = @g + 'or firstname  like''' +('a'= 'a')+ '''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base query should have `1=1`

```
set @g = 'select *
from person.person
where 1=1 '
set @g = @g + 'and firstname like ''%t'' '
set @g = @g + 'or firstname  like ''' +('a'= 'a')+ ''''
```

If you need to group the conditions they all need to be together:

```
set @g = @g +'(firstname like ''%t%'' or firstname like ''%a'')'
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate an injection. When you try injecting '1=1'-- its a variable varchar value. Besides I just tried it and Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: thats what I got